# Insert default value via EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have default constraint on my caption field in database. In web app if caption is empty NULL value passed to database and database returns exception because samo field it cannot be null (Caption varchar(50) NOT NULL).

So, what is easiest way to set some value ("" - empty string) or avoid to send NULL to database if value is really not provided. How I can set that in EntityFrameowrk, or maybe in data access layer...?

Answer (score 1):

Just define property with empty string right after new entity creation. For example, within constructor. [Example](http://www.prescottnasser.com/post/2012/05/16/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Default-Column-Values.aspx)

Before update existing entity, you can check property for null:

```
entity.StringProperty = entity.StringProperty ?? String.Empty;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

On my system MVC4 entity framework 5.0 I am using like this, (DataAnnotation)

```
[DefaultValue = DateTime.Now]
```

public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }

}

Or like this for others Types... `string.Empty`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue which only you will know. The null value represents business logic and that is for you to figure out.

Should the database be changed to allow the null because it has meaning there?

Should the application save "-1" in the database because that has some meaning, or should it save ""?

Should the application not commit the field at all if that value is null?

Does allowing the application to submit a field with data which is not relevant affect the future value of that data?

In my experience, I have allowed values to be placed in the database as `NULL` when the null represents an absence of relation or value. When that value is absent, that implies that an action which should or will take place has not occurred. This is just for myself though, because most people implement business logic on a case by case basis.

Comment: Database doesn't allow to insert NULL values.

Comment: @user1810618 - You can change the field to allow NULL.

Comment: I cannot do that because I don't have access to change database schema.

Comment: @user1810618 - Then mark the field as `[Required]`, or provide a default value of `""` inside of a constructor, or when committing the data, ensure that the value is at least `""`. It really depends on what an empty value means in that position. Username should probably not be "", whereas it may not matter if nickname is "" (provided nickname is not the only association).

Answer (score 0):

In Entity, can you initialize your object on creation?  I know you can do it in Linq.  Are you able to go inside the code for the entity object and set the property in question to a default value on creation?

Answer (score 0):

set it in the constructor.

```
partial class MyEntityName {
    public MyEntityName() {
        this.Caption = "";
    }
}
```